# How can I size QMovie?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qmovie

```py
self.MovieLabel = QLabel()
movie = QMovie('C:/Users/Kaan/Desktop/Tasarımlar/Mary/animasyon_mary/wait.gif')
self.MovieLabel.setMovie(movie)
movie.start()
```

How can i resize QMovie with QLabel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable the scaledContents property of the QLabel:

```
self.MovieLabel.setScaledContents(True)
```